# bootstrap nav - last three <li> not linking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I know it is frowned on but if anybody wants to see in situ take a look at http://sigsample.info/tami (apologies for posting this link)

Here's the code, the navbar (bootstrap 2) works fine apart from the three graphics at the end. any idea what I have done wrong?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.php"><br />
                Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><br />
                About</a></li>
            <li><a href="listings.php"><br />
                Listings</a></li>
            <li><a href="ask_tami.php"><br />
                Ask Tami</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Buying<br />
                a Home<b class="caret"></b> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="tools.php" style="text-align:left">Tools and Apps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="process.php" style="text-align:left">Buying Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rentvbuy.php" style="text-align:left">Rent vs Buy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="firsttime.php" style="text-align:left">First Time Buyers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="foreclosures.php" style="text-align:left">Foreclosures</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.eralisting.info/" target="_blank">Selling<br />
                a Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="glossary.php">Glossary<br />
                of Terms</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mortgage<br />
                & Finances<b class="caret"></b> </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="loan_process.php" style="text-align:left">The Loan Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="affordability.php" style="text-align:left">Affordability</a></li>
                    <li><a href="closing.php" style="text-align:left">Prepare for Closing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="closing_costs.php" style="text-align:left">Closing Costs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="preapproval.php" style="text-align:left">Pre-Approval</a></li>
                    <li><a href="calculator.php" style="text-align:left">Payment Calculator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.eramortgage.com" target="_blank" style="text-align:left">ERA Mortgages</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php"><img src="mail.png" alt="Email Me" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tami.newman.3"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /> </a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two elements like this, one of which is empty and overlays the nav bar:

```
<span class="headshot"></span>
```

Remove the empty second one and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

it's your your .headshot css, try removing the width and height

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 738px;
 top: -99px;
```